# paging is not working properly on news archives page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I need paging on news archives page. Data is coming correctly if display all records on same page. But if i add paging code, then pagination values (such as 1,2,3,...16) coming correctly, but if i click on page 2 then it displays the same post title as on page 1.

```
    <h1 style="margin-left:10px;">News</h1>

    <ul class="years">
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$all_posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
 'posts_per_page' => 20,
  'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged='. $paged,
));

    // this variable will contain all the posts in a associative array
    // with three levels, for every year, month and posts.

    $ordered_posts = array();

    foreach ($all_posts as $single) {

      $year  = mysql2date('Y', $single->post_date);
      $month = mysql2date('F', $single->post_date);

      // specifies the position of the current post
      $ordered_posts[$year][$month][] = $single;

    }

    // iterates the years
    foreach ($ordered_posts as $year => $months) { ?>
      <li>
        <h3><?php echo $year ?></h3>
        <ul class="months">
        <?php foreach ($months as $month => $posts ) { // iterates the moths ?>
          <li>
            <h3><?php printf("%s (%d)", $month, count($months[$month])) ?></h3>
            <ul class="posts">
              <?php foreach ($posts as $single ) { // iterates the posts ?>
                <li>
                  <?php echo mysql2date('F j', $single->post_date) ?> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($single->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($single->ID); ?></a>  (<?php echo $single->comment_count ?>)</li>
                </li>

              <?php } // ends foreach $posts ?>
            </ul> <!-- ul.posts -->
          </li>
        <?php } // ends foreach for $months ?>
        </ul> <!-- ul.months -->
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
        wp_paginate();
    }  ?>
      </li> <?php
    } // ends foreach for $ordered_posts
    ?>

    </ul><!-- ul.years -->
```

here is the screen shot:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using your custom `get_posts()` you are ignoring the `$paged` var. In this way, you'll see always posts from the first page.

According the [Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) if you would like to alter the main query before it is executed, you can hook into it using `pre_get_posts`.

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
    $query->set('post_type', array('news'));
    $query->set('orderby', 'date');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

In this way the `$paged` var is maintened from the main query.

You can also check if the main query is in a specific archive or whatever, in the hook function.

Comment: Thanks for the help...But not working.. i have corrected my code...and edit it here also. please see the above code now. But problem now i'm facing is "It displaying empty pages in the paging". e.g. there are 100 post in news section. If i set the post per page limit to 20 then there should be 1,2,3,4,5 in the pagination. But it is displaying 20 (1,2,3,4,5,...,19,20)numbers. which is wrong. dont know whats problem here

Comment: now it has a syntax error: use `'paged' => $paged` instead of `'paged='. $paged,`. I suggest you to use the `pre_get_post` hook strategy. It is much more maintainable.